# Label not updating

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm trying to create a GUI using `tkinter`. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

B3Questions = ["How is a cactus adapted to a desert environment?", "What factors could cause a species to become extinct?"] 
B3Answers = ["It has leaves reduced to spines to cut water loss, a thick outer layer to cut down water loss and a deep-wide spreading root system to obtain as much water as possible", "Increased competition, new predators and new diseases"]
B3Possibles = [x for x in range (len(B3Questions))]

def loadGUI():

    root = Tk() #Blank Window

    questNum = generateAndCheck()
    questionToPrint = StringVar()
    answer = StringVar()

    def showQuestion():

        questionToPrint.set(B3Questions[questNum])

    def showAnswer():

        answer.set(B3Answers[questNum])

    def reloadGUI():

        global questNum
        questNum = generateAndCheck()
        return questNum

    question = Label(root, textvariable = questionToPrint)
    question.pack()

    answerLabel = Label(root, textvariable = answer, wraplength = 400)
    answerLabel.pack()

    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.pack()
    revealAnswer = Button(bottomFrame, text="Reveal Answer", command=showAnswer)
    revealAnswer.pack(side=LEFT)
    nextQuestion = Button(bottomFrame, text="Next Question", command=reloadGUI)
    nextQuestion.pack(side=LEFT)

    showQuestion()
    root.mainloop()

def generateAndCheck():

    questNum = randint(0, 1)
    print(questNum)

    if questNum not in B3Possibles:
        generateAndCheck()
    else:
        B3Possibles.remove(questNum)
        return questNum
```

Basically, when pressing "Next Question", the question label does not update. Pressing "Next Question" again will throw the code into a nice loop of errors.

I honestly cannot see where I'm going wrong, but that's likely due to my lack of experience

Comment: You're not actually updating the content of the `StringVar` `questionToPrint` when you call `reloadGUI()`.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: The error you receive after pressing Next Question a second time is that there is nothing in your list of numbers. Therefore your function `reloadGUI` will keep running until you hit Python's recursive limit.

Comment: People this is a **new user of SO**. Could we ease up on the downvotes and the close votes please?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the short answer is that you're not actually updating the content of the `StringVar` `questionToPrint`. I would fix this by changing the `reloadGUI()` function to this:

```
def reloadGUI():
    global questNum
    questNum = generateAndCheck()
    showQuestion()
    answer.set("")  # Clear the answer for the new question
```

Also, as Dzhao pointed out, the reason you're getting an error after you run out of questions is because you need to put some sort of protection within your `generateAndCheck()` function to prevent against infinite recursion.

Additionally, I would recommend you change the way you determine what question to ask because the way you have it right now is needlessly complicated. Look in to the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module a little more, particularly the [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) function. You'll notice it raises an `IndexError` when the list is empty, so you can catch that error and that will help solve the problem that Dzhao had pointed out.

Comment: This results in the same effect as before - the question label doesn't change, and the loop of errors occurs

Answer (score 0):

RobertR answered your first question. The reason why you receive an error when pressing the `Next Question` button again is because your list, `B3Possibilities` has two numbers, 0 and 1. So when you run the function twice, you'll remove both one and zero from this list. Then you have an empty list. When you call `reloadGUI` a third time you'll never hit your `else` statement because the `randint` generated will NEVER be in `B3Possibilites`. Your `if` clause is called and you dive into an un-ending recursive call.

A solution to this might be to have a check in your `generageAndCheck` function:

```
if(len(B3Possibiles) == 0):
    #run some code. Maybe restart the program?
```